# VBA Paste Variable Range to Other Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I've got a macro set up to identify bad data, but when I try to copy only the clean data it throws an error (Error Code 1004). I'm using a For loop with a series of if statements to build the clean data range. Not sure why it is throwing this error as the line above "clean_Range.Interior.Color = Clean_Color" is working just fine and the "Data Sheet" tab appears to be active...

Any thoughts?

The data array is selected by the user, then we look at the limits of the upper and lower bounds to build the clean vs. dirty data array (~30 lines from the end).
Code and Image below:

```
Sub Data_cleanse()
'Perform Stats Analysis on Outlier Data.

'Specify Dims.....
Dim count_data_analyzed As Variant
Dim allRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range, selectedRng As Range
Dim ws_instruction As Worksheet, ws_data As Worksheet, ws_output As Worksheet, ws_cleansed As Worksheet
Dim record_cell As Variant, Upper_limit As Variant, Lower_limit As Variant, count_outliers As Variant
Dim percent_outliers As Variant
Dim AnswerYes As String, AnswerNo As String
Dim yesRange As Range, noRange As Range, dirty_range As Range, clean_Range As Range

'Highlight Outlier Data Points
Const yesColor As Long = 65280
Const noColor As Long = 65535
Const Clean_Color As Long = 65535

'Ascribe worksheets
Set ws_instruction = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instruction Sheet")
Set ws_data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Sheet")
Set ws_output = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output Sheet")
Set ws_cleansed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cleansed Data")

ExcludeNegatives = MsgBox("Should all negative values be excluded from analysis?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Repsonse")
ExcludeZeros = MsgBox("Should zero values be excluded from analysis?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Repsonse")
Set selectedRng = Application.Selection

'Error handling to capture Cancel key.
On Error GoTo errHandler

'Define range.
Set selectedRng = Application.InputBox("Range", , selectedRng.Address, Type:=8)
record_cell = selectedRng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                           RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
'Cells(1, 9).Value = record_cell
'Cells(1, 10).Value = record_cell

'Format Output Information
ws_output.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Analysis Table"
ws_output.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Data Range Analyzed"
ws_output.Cells(6, 1).Value = "Upper Limit"
ws_output.Cells(7, 1).Value = "Lower Limit"
ws_output.Cells(8, 1).Value = "Number of Outliers"
ws_output.Cells(9, 1).Value = "Percent of Data"

Upper_limit = 15
Lower_limit = -20

If ExcludeNegatives = vbYes And Lower_limit < 0 Then
    Lower_limit = 0
Else
    Lower_limit = -20
End If

'If ExcludeZeros = vbYes Then...... may not need to do anything here.....
ws_output.Cells(2, 2).Value = record_cell
ws_output.Cells(6, 2).Value = Upper_limit
ws_output.Cells(7, 2).Value = Lower_limit

'Error Handling
On Error GoTo errHandler

'Build Array of Outlier Data
Set allRange = selectedRng
For Each aCell In allRange.Cells
   If IsNumeric(aCell) Then ' maybe you don't need this...
      If aCell.Value > Upper_limit Or aCell.Value < Lower_limit Then
         If yesRange Is Nothing Then
            Set yesRange = aCell
         Else
            Set yesRange = Union(aCell, yesRange)
         End If
      Else
         If noRange Is Nothing Then
            Set noRange = aCell
         Else
            Set noRange = Union(aCell, noRange)
         End If
      End If
   End If
Next aCell
'Highlight Outlier Data
yesRange.Interior.Color = yesColor

'Build Array of Clean Data
For Each bCell In allRange.Cells
    If IsNumeric(bCell) Then
        If bCell.Value < Upper_limit And bCell.Value > Lower_limit Then
            If clean_Range Is Nothing Then
                Set clean_Range = bCell
            Else
                Set clean_Range = Union(bCell, clean_Range)
            End If
        Else
            If dirty_range Is Nothing Then
                Set dirty_range = bCell
            Else
                Set dirty_range = Union(bCell, dirty_range)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next bCell

'Highlight Clean Data
clean_Range.Interior.Color = Clean_Color
clean_Range.Copy
'ws_data.Range("A2").PasteSpecial

'Stop before running error handling.
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'Quit sub procedure when user clicks InputBox Cancel button.
If Err.Number = 424 Then
    Exit Sub
Else: MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number, vbOK
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error description (e.g. `This action won't work on multiple selections.`)? You might consider adding it to the message box prompt.

Comment: @VBasic2008, your e.g. was spot on. The message that displays is "this action won't work on multiple selections. What's odd is that seems to be the error even if the individual selects 1 array of cells...

Comment: If you want to copy a non-contiguous range, for rows it has to have the same number of columns and vice versa e.g. you cannot copy the range `Range("A1:C3, D4")` but you could copy e.g. the range `Range("A1:A3, C1:C3")` or `Range("A1:C1, A3:C3")`.

Comment: Since you've already defined the source range for the copy (`clean_Range`), why not simply process each cell of that (i.e. do the transfer cell-by-cell)? After all, it's not a lot a data, so won't take very long.